# Invalid Selection Range when I attempt to extract component from svelte

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm just learning svelte, so I may be doing something terribly wrong.

Anyways, when I try to extract my button component, whether I set the component name to `./Button.svelte`, `./Button`, `Button.svelte`, and same with no capitalization, it produces an error ["Invalid selection range"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJGCe.png).

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    
    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<button>Hello!</button>
```

As shown above, I am just trying to export the button component.

[Here's the project organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nUmt.png)

I tried renaming the component name, which produced the same result. I fully restarted my computer many times, also producing the same result. I also tried to reload VSCode, which also produced the same result.

Comment: I believe the markup has to do something, try adding a listener or variable to the mix and see if it works, but this entire "extract component" is kind of experimental if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue, when attempting to complete the Fireship.io course I was unable to make the...

```
<button>Hello!</button>
```

into a extracted component.

I fixed it by adding a blank line below. Then repeating the steps to extract the component I no longer receive the range error.